# Seleniumbase: Intercept HTTP requests

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, seleniumbase

With Selenium Wire, you can intercept your requests like this:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver 

def intercept_response(request, response):
        print(request.headers)
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.response_interceptor = intercept_response
```

This prints a continuous stream of data for every request you make.

I attempted to do the same thing with SeleniumBase, but it doesn't work. The following only prints a single GET request, but the linkedIn page that I am visiting should yield multiple GET requests.

```
from seleniumbase import Driver
driver = Driver(browser="chrome", pls="eager", agent=agent, proxy=proxy, headed=True, wire=True)

driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com")
for request in driver.requests:
    print(request.url)
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is the `selenium-wire` version:

```py
from seleniumwire import webdriver

def intercept_response(request, response):
    print(request.headers)

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.response_interceptor = intercept_response
driver.get("https://wikipedia.org")
driver.quit()
```

Then the [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) equivalent would be:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

def intercept_response(request, response):
    print(request.headers)

driver = Driver(wire=True)
driver.response_interceptor = intercept_response
driver.get("https://wikipedia.org")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Hey, big fan of your work. I tried the code above and it works beautifully, the problem I can now see is that I have driver = Driver(wire=True, proxy=proxy) Is there some way to have a proxy AND have the HTTP requests printed out?

Comment: I tried it, and it works using the `sbase proxy` command, which creates a local proxy server on `127.0.0.1:8899`. Use `Driver(wire=True, proxy="127.0.0.1:8899")` to run on it. `sbase proxy` was recently added, and uses https://github.com/abhinavsingh/proxy.py for creating the local proxy server.